# How to make a button with dynamic runtime changeable Background Color

Tags: xaml, resources

I want to create a button with defined style and
I want to change the button Background Color in application runtime.
I think that this must be done with bindings, but I don't know how to do it.
I have the following XAML code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="EmkoGasButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="SlateGray" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" 
                                                    ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#00000000"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      TextElement.FontWeight="Bold">
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>

                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                        <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                                <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF303030" Offset="0.3"/>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="grid" Value="0.25"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Application.Resources>
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to accomplish? You're writing that you want to change a button at runtime, but what is supposed to make the button change its appearance? A click? Some other event? You'll need to specify this and also explain what you've already tried.

Comment: Some clarifications: The conditions for changing button background color is not related with the button - external events. I tried to create a custom property and bind it to the color, but I do not succeed.

Comment: Please update the answer directly and show the relevant bits of code. Right now, you're only showing your application's Resources, but it would be necessary to also see the XAML/code behind with the Button as well as the ViewModel, if you have one. There are different ways to accomplish this, but it is tedious to show a practical way without being able to see what you've already done so far.